# svn status in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

Which is the right-click equivalent to `svn status` in [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)? TortoiseSVN is a Windows' GUI for Subversion.

Comment: do you mean the status of files like modified, conflict, etc?

Comment: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see all local changes in "TortoiseSVN > Check for modifications". The "Check repository" button will also look for remote updates.

But you can do the same by opening the commit window - it's the same as long as you don't click on the commit button accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

Try the "Check for updates" command.

Answer (score 0):

"Check for Updates"

Comment: or even "Check for modifications..." - doh! Can't say I've ever used it though - AndiDog's observation regarding the commit window is what I've always done. +1 on that - I'd vote it up but don't have the rep yet.

Answer (score -2):

If you have the icon overlays turned on, you can just look at your working copy folder and the icons will give you much of this information.